# Compiling a program without the the Multi Threaded DLL (Visual C++ 2010)

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio-2010, winapi, opengl, dll

By default, Visual Studio compiles a project to use the Multi Threaded DLL, found in the Visual Studio runtime. I want to compile my program using only /MT instead of /MD. Granted, that most systems already have this installed, and it's also available as a re-distributable.

When I change /MD to /MT, I get an error:

> MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _free already defined in LIBCMT.lib(free.obj)

And four or five similar errors.
To try and fix this I removed LIBCMT.LIB from the default libraries.

I then get the error:

> libcpmt.lib(_tolower.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __calloc_crt referenced in function __Getctype

Removing MSVCRTD.lib from the default list leads to similar errors? 
It should be noted that:
-This is an OpenGL project, using the [glfw](http://www.glfw.org/) library.
-I am using the SOIL image library by lonesock for texture loading.

Comment: What are your build settings? Because MSVCRTD is the debug version of MSVCRT.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resolving LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007312/resolving-lnk4098-defaultlib-msvcrt-conflicts-with)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any further precise information, I would say your first problem is that you're somehow mixing release and debug versions of libraries. MSVCRTD.lib is the debug version of MSVCRT.lib.

Either you have some debug settings hanging around in your own projects, or you're linking against debug versions of libraries you're using.

Never ever mix debug and release versions. If you're lucky you get an error like this. In some rare situations all magically seems to work until it doesn't.