# SOIL not linking correctly

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, soil

I am linking SOIL in my library but when I compile I get these linker errors:

```
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>libSOIL.lib(stb_image_aug.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __alloca referenced in function _stbi_zlib_decode_noheader_buffer
1>libSOIL.lib(image_helper.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sqrtf referenced in function _RGBE_to_RGBdivA2
```

I did link libSOIL.lib in the addition dependencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The unresolved symbol errors, error LNK2019, are from the symbols in libgcc.lib or another standard library implementation (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh(v=vs.100).aspx) for the Microsoft Options) not being linked to. alloca and sqrtf are both standard library functions.

If you aren't linking to a standard library, then link to one by adding it to your linker library path.

From the warning above warning LNK4098, it is more likely you are linking to a standard library but the linker doesn't know which on to load.

Recommend LINKER arguments to make this problem go away (tell the linker to choose a specific standard library) are /NODEFAULTLIB:"MSVCRT" /NODEFAULTLIB:"LIBCMT.

See the following links for additional information and resources

- [Linker Tools Warning LNK4098](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa267384(v=vs.60).aspx)
- [Linking problems *SOLVED*](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/500069-linking-problems-solved/)
- [Default Libraries in Visual C++](http://binglongx.wordpress.com/tag/nodefaultlib/)
- [Resolving LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007312/resolving-lnk4098-defaultlib-msvcrt-conflicts-with)

Comment: Hmm, adding /NODEFAULTLIB:MSVCRT fixed the warning but the same errors are still there.

Answer (score 7):

Fixed the error.

Although I'm using VC2010, I built the VC8 libraries. I then added SOIL.lib instead of libSOIL.lib. Errors went away.

Comment: I was using VC2012 (called VC11) and building VC9 solution worked too.

Comment: I was using VC2013 and building VC8 solution worked

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue (using Visual Studio 2013 with vc120 toolset), I solved it downloading the SOIL library from the official site and instead of renaming `libSOIL.a` to `SOIL.lib` I ran the VC8 solution inside the official zip (that creates you the `SOIL.lib`)´then I copied it to my project and the problems went away.

Comment: This worked for me too. VC8 instead of VC9 for VS 2013