# SOIL library - unable to link

Tags: c++, linker, soil

While building my project, I get the same issue, solved in this links:
[SOIL not linking correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629349/soil-not-linking-correctly), 
[SOIL set-up in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009049/soil-set-up-in-visual-studio-2010)

I tried every suggested solution:

- build the VC8 and VC9 libraries to get the SOIL.lib (I'm using VS 2013)
- linked the libraries (Linker - Additional Dependencies)
- renamed the libSoil.a to SOIL.lib

but still having the same errors:

```
   1>libSOIL.a(stb_image_aug.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __alloca referenced in function    _stbi_zlib_decode_noheader_buffer
   1>libSOIL.a(image_helper.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sqrtf referenced in function _RGBE_to_RGBdivA2
```

Any ideas , other solutions?

Comment: did you check that link in duplicate ?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: check out this link.

"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix"