# What is linking to MSVCRTD?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

We are building a rather large and complex program with an abundance of dependencies with visual studio 2008. When we run the 64-bit build on our Windows test system, it fails to run warning about some SxS problem.

After digging around a bit, we came to realize that the manifest file contains

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity type='win32' name='Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT' version='9.0.21022.8' processorArchitecture='amd64' publicKeyToken='1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b' />
</dependentAssembly>
```

I looked over the build log and linked the project with `/VERBOSE:LIB` and see

```
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
...
1>Searching libraries
...
1>    Searching c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\lib\amd64\MSVCRTD.lib:
```

I ran `dumpbin /DIRECTIVES` on all the .obj files, but see no reference to msvcrtd.lib

This is a release build. Why is it trying to link in MSVCRTD?

Is there a way i can generate a table of functions linked from msvcrtd?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resolving LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007312/resolving-lnk4098-defaultlib-msvcrt-conflicts-with)

Answer (score 1):

oops, asked this question a bit too hastily. the solution is to add `/MAP` to the linker option.

Comment: Very helpful ist /verbose too