# Am I linking it right?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, linker

So I downloaded this rar from the opengl red book:http://www.opengl-redbook.com/Code/oglpg-8th-edition.zip

And what I do is this:

1. Open a new empty Project
2. Browse to the project properties -> Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories
3. Add the lib and include folders from the downloaded Winrar.

That's all I do and when I run the project I get a lot of error's :\

What did I do wrong and what should I do to make it work for me?

EDIT: those are the errors i get:

```
Warning 7   warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library   C:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RedBook\RedBook\LINK    RedBook
Warning 1   warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'double' to 'GLfloat'   c:\users\naor\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\redbook\redbook\source.cpp  25  1   RedBook
Warning 2   warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'double' to 'GLfloat'   c:\users\naor\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\redbook\redbook\source.cpp  26  1   RedBook
Warning 3   warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'double' to 'GLfloat'   c:\users\naor\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\redbook\redbook\source.cpp  27  1   RedBook
Warning 4   warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'double' to 'GLfloat'   c:\users\naor\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\redbook\redbook\source.cpp  28  1   RedBook
Warning 5   warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'double' to 'GLfloat'   c:\users\naor\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\redbook\redbook\source.cpp  29  1   RedBook
Warning 6   warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'double' to 'GLfloat'   c:\users\naor\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\redbook\redbook\source.cpp  30  1   RedBook
Error   8   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _LoadShaders referenced in function "void __cdecl init(void)" (?init@@YAXXZ)  C:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RedBook\RedBook\Source.obj  RedBook
Error   9   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RedBook\Debug\RedBook.exe   1   1   RedBook
```

And that's the code:http://pastebin.com/X55tVP3d

Comment: Have you ever used VisualStudio before?

Comment: can you post the errors?

Comment: I did.
and yes I will edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `warning LNK4098` => The first warning indicates that your project is using a C runtime different than the one used by your dependencies (typically static vs dynamic, release vs debug). This is controlled by the settings `Code Generation` > `Runtime Library`
   Details can be found here: [Resolving LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007312/resolving-lnk4098-defaultlib-msvcrt-conflicts-with)
2. `error LNK2019` => The linker could not find the definition of `LoadShaders` used in the function `init(void)`. Either you forgot to add a `cpp` file containing the definition of `LoadShaders`, or you forgot to add a lib in your project.

Comment: What can I do to fix the warning?
I added the cpp and these are the error's:http://pastebin.com/Y1WxZ58W

Comment: I updated the answer. In your case, I think your project uses the static debug version, whereas your dependencies use the dynamic debug version. Could you check the setting of your project? Is it /MTd?

Comment: I dont have /MTd as an option.
My settings are on /MDd

Comment: Ok, then using /MTd in your settings should fix the C run time consistency. Could you kindly confirm?

Comment: Nope, it didn't work :\
What should i do about the cpp file? i keep getting the error's i posted above

Comment: I see. I checked the package you mentionned in the question, and i think the LNK4098 warning is due to dependencies not related to oglpg. I am afraid you have to check the run time used by your dlls

Comment: I am new to this do you have any idea how do i do this? :\