# Visual Studio 2013 linker confusion

Tags: c++

I get the following errors when compiling(running build in VS) my latest project.
I have read other questions/answers here on this site, but so far no luck to fix my issues.

I know my problems are related to linking the different libraries, but why I get this problems I don't know.

The compiling has been working OK before, but no I can't get rid of the errors.

Any help would be fine.

Here is my error list and configuration file

```
>1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z) already defined in libcpmt.lib(xthrow.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(char const * const &)" (??0exception@std@@QAE@ABQBD@Z) already defined in LIBCMT.lib(stdexcpt.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall std::exception::~exception(void)" (??1exception@std@@UAE@XZ) already defined in LIBCMT.lib(stdexcpt.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: __vsnprintf_s already defined in LIBCMT.lib(vsnprnc.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(class std::exception const &)" (??0exception@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z) already defined in LIBCMT.lib(stdexcpt.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _atoi already defined in LIBCMT.lib(atox.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _memmove already defined in LIBCMT.lib(memmove.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _printf already defined in LIBCMT.lib(printf.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(ti_inst.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: __thiscall type_info::type_info(class type_info const &)" (??0type_info@@AAE@ABV0@@Z) already defined in LIBCMT.lib(typinfo.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(ti_inst.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: class type_info & __thiscall type_info::operator=(class type_info const &)" (??4type_info@@AAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z) already defined in LIBCMT.lib(typinfo.obj)
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
```

>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{94CF9190-4DC8-4B09-9579-CF385879D9B5}</ProjectGuid>
    <Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>
    <RootNamespace>OC</RootNamespace>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <ProjectName>OCP4NGX</ProjectName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v100</PlatformToolset>
    <CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v100</PlatformToolset>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
    <CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <LinkIncremental>false</LinkIncremental>
    <IgnoreImportLibrary>true</IgnoreImportLibrary>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>NotUsing</PrecompiledHeader>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_DEBUG;_WINDOWS;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreadedDebug</RuntimeLibrary>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Windows</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <AdditionalOptions>simconnect.lib wsock32.lib %(AdditionalOptions)</AdditionalOptions>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Lockheed Martin\Prepar3D v2 SDK 2.1.9936.0\Utilities\SimConnect SDK\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <PrecompiledHeader>NotUsing</PrecompiledHeader>
      <Optimization>MaxSpeed</Optimization>
      <FunctionLevelLinking>true</FunctionLevelLinking>
      <IntrinsicFunctions>true</IntrinsicFunctions>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;NDEBUG;_WINDOWS;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <MinimalRebuild>true</MinimalRebuild>
      <RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreaded</RuntimeLibrary>
      <FavorSizeOrSpeed>Speed</FavorSizeOrSpeed>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Windows</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Lockheed Martin\Prepar3D v2 SDK 2.1.9936.0\Utilities\SimConnect SDK\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <AdditionalOptions>simconnect.lib wsock32.lib %(AdditionalOptions)</AdditionalOptions>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Text Include="OC.txt" />
    <Text Include="ReadMe.txt" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="err.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="IOCPClient.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="logger.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="NGXConnector.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="OC.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="PMDG_NGX_SDK.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="resource.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="settings.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="simconnect.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="stdafx.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="targetver.h" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="err.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="IOCPClient.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="logger.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="NGXConnector.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="OC.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="settings.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="stdafx.cpp">
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
    </ClCompile>
    <ClCompile Include="Var_Event.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ResourceCompile Include="OC.rc" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Image Include="OC.ico" />
    <Image Include="small.ico" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="OCrc.txt" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: What do you need the Lockheed Martin Prepar3D SDK for?

Comment: It at least looks your linking an obj or lib that is built configured for using the static CRT, while your project is linking against the dynamic CRT. Does their SDK include a lib/dll pair that is bound to dynamic CRT ? Or did you recently change which code-generation style your project uses?

Comment: Lockheed Martin, don't they make weapons of war? I think answering this question would conflict with my personal ethics :-P

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the following answer?
[Resolving LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3007915/3337518)

There are some helps there.