# FLTK in xCode math.h error

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, fltk

I have been trying to set up FLTK in xCode. After a little struggling I thought I was successful in linking all the libraries, etc... However, I am now getting the following error from the math.h file located in the FL/include folder:

```
'/usr/include/math.h'file not found
```

from the following code:

```
// Xcode on OS X includes files by recursing down into directories.
// This code catches the cycle and directly includes the required file.

#ifdef fl_math_h_cyclic_include 
#  include "/usr/include/math.h"
#endif
```

I have read through a few different solutions posted before, but none of them are seeming to work for me. There is no file `math.h` located in that directory. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem trying to use FLTK .lib files in Visual Studio 2015 Community. After a bit of searching, this Stackoverflow page gave me the right hint:

[Resolving LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007312/resolving-lnk4098-defaultlib-msvcrt-conflicts-with)

The mistake I was making is that I built the FLTK .lib files myself a long time ago and forgot what setting I used.

In my new Project for which FLTK was needed, I needed the following settings in VS2015(that was forced by another library I wanted to use together with FLTK):
Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Runtime Library I needed Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)

It turned out that I built the FLTK .libs a year before using

Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)
instead of
Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)

I did two things:
Rebuilt the FLTK libraries in VS2015 with the correct settings and

in the FL folder in FLTK, I renamed the math.h file to Fl_math.h

Which solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on Linux.  The way I got around it was

1. In the FL directory, rename math.h to Fl_math.h
2. In all the files that #include FL/math.h change to FL/Fl_math.h

The base problem is that constants like M_E are not defined by default so Fl_math.h defines them.  On the Linux/MS environment, all Fl_math.h needs to do is

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>
```

The Xcode environment might be the same.