# TDM-GCC c++ compiler (Setting up)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mingw-w64, tdm-gcc

I'm now using TDM-GCC 64 bit compiler and have originally built all my libraries (dependencies for other libraries) and projects using this compiler to create 64 bit binaries (which is what I want).

Recently I have run into some build issues where I was building a Fast Light Tool Kit (gui toolkit) project which included math.h.  This is where I ran into my first build issue and made me realize that I've probably set up my build environment incorrectly.  Everything was built using MSYS.

My root directory is C:\mingw so when I configured each project I used the commands:
./configure --prefix=c:\mingw and the appropriate c:\mingw include and lib directories were created (c:\mingw\include & c:\mingw\lib).

FLTK contains a math.h file which directs the compiler to search for the appropriate math.h c++ file in the relevant include directory but the issue is it is telling me it can't find it (math.h: no such file or director etc). I'm using Windows 7 64 bit.

I think this is because the way I have set up my build environment, I have maybe not accounted for the fact that TDM-GCC can compile both 32 and 64 bit binaries so this somehow has affected the compilers interpretation of where my c++ math.h file is.

I looked on this explanation of how to go about building libraries using Mingw64 on this link:  [enter link description here](http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-3.0.0-BETA/mingw64_how_to.html) but I think TDM-GCC has taken care of a few of the problems this article is designed to resolve.

How do I set up my build environment correctly for the TDM-GCC 64 bit compiler so all my directories are found?

I noticed there are a number of include directories:

1. **C:\mingw\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include**
2. **C:\mingw\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\5.1.0\include**

PLUS my own directory created when I build my projects

1. **C:\mingw\include**

**What am I doing wrong here?  Should I have used one of the first two directories as my include directory?**  I think this where I have baused things up.

Comment: This could be relevant, http://stackoverflow.com/a/26339417/5781248

Comment: Actually it goes some way to helping.  I see from the FLTK  previous bugs which have now been resolved that this problem is common.  Link below if anyone needs it.  Thanks for the response.        http://www.fltk.org/str.php?L785+P0+S0+C0+I0+E0+V%25+Qmath    I thought is was the build environment that was the problem..