# Change cl/link.exe default libraries from cmdline?

Tags: c++, linker, cl.exe

I'm trying to understand some of the fundamental windows libraries, as well as the C standard library. I currently use VS 2013.

I switched to command line compiling in order to try and have more control over which libraries are linked in, so that I can see which functions/headers resolve to which libraries. However, cl.exe (I haven't tried individual compilation/linkage) seems to be automatically including a number of libraries, as I can successfully compile and execute a number of programs with dependencies (core ones like input/output) without specifying any libraries myself.

Does the cl.exe compiler automatically include a number of libraries even from the command line, if so, how can I change this!?

Thanks!
Renzo.

Comment: Google is your friend. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0zzbyt4.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tz4da4a.aspx

Comment: Second link was great help, thanks. I had consulted the documentation, but it was difficult for me as a beginner to follow. /NODEFAULTLIB is what is was looking for. To get started however, I need to know what libraries are being included by default. I can't find an actual list of these in the MS documentation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3007915/17034

Comment: @Renzokuken I was aware you needed the second link, but I posted the first for a reason too. If you ever need to find linker options, look at it.

Comment: @Hans Passant & deviantfan Both v. useful links, thank you.