# Get rid of msvcr120.dll/msvcp120.dll dependency in my Release application (VC++ 2013)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, dll

I know that there are some questions about how to include msvcr120.dll/msvcp120.dll into your project.

But I want to drop that dependency. I compile the program in Release version, in Visual Studio 2013. I do not depend on any VS-specific commands (`#pragma` etc.) or precompiled headers etc.

I want to compile it to one **single release .exe and provide it to user WITHOUT demanding him to install VC++ Redistributes for VS** (the user will be working on Windows 7, Windows 8, maybe Windows XP).

Is that possible? If so, how?

Comment: You will have to use the static runtime if you do not want the redistributable.

Comment: Should I use /MT option then? And the same for any of .lib I compile and include into project? What with 3rd-party .dll files?

Comment: `#pragma` and most VS specific commands don't depend on the msvcr.  Having _globals_ depends on the c++ runtime.  It's also the thing that calls main.  You need that code.  However, as drescherjm says, you can embed that lib code in your exe (via the `/MT` or `/MTd` option), and then you don't need a seperate dll file.

Comment: ***What with 3rd-party .dll files?*** You would have to avoid these. Although I thought you were already doing that with the single exe.

Comment: @drescherjm yes, I'm sorry - it was a simplification for the question. I want single .exe + opengl dll files (which are not part of VC and that's why I ignored them in the first place). Can you make an answer from your comment about MT? I can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can statically link the runtime to your project by setting the `/MT` flag. You can find this option in Visual Studio 2013 under **Project** > **[ProjectName] Properties...** > **Configuration Properties** > **C/C++** > **Code Generation** > **Runtime Library**. Make sure to only set it for the **Release** configuration.

Comment: I would recommend this as an accepted answer because it clearly describes what it has to be done. Indicating the comments does not provide an eloquent answer for the end user.

Comment: I was facing the same problem even after changing it to MT it still giving error message to msvcr120.dll not found

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Just like the guy above. I switched to /MT, my output file did not change size and I am still dependent on msvcr120.dll

Comment: I got this to work but I also had to add the following additional command line arguments to the linker: /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrt.lib /defaultlib:libcmt.lib

Answer (score 3):

From the comments. To remove the requirement of possibly needing the redistributable you can build your application with the static runtime (/MT option) instead of either of the dynamic runtime choices.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are there any side-effects for this approach? It's possible to add the .lib that was not build with `/MT` option to project with `/MT` option? If not, how can I determine that e.g. some 3rd party library has been build with or without `/MT` option?

Comment: 3rd party dlls will most likely use /MD which you want to prevent this is why you will need to avoid these.

Comment: @dreschermj - hm, ok. But still, it's very non-elegant to demand from user to instal VC++ redistributes in order to run my game/application. I personally don't like when installer tries to install them or other shared resources along with the app I wanted to install.

Comment: For static libraries you will get a warning if the static library depends on a dynamic CRT. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007312/resolving-lnk4098-defaultlib-msvcrt-conflicts-with

Comment: In my applications (medical imaging research - so not used by many) I package the runtime in my installer and have it as an optional (default off) component in the installer.

Comment: ok, thanks once again :) I will use `/MT` option now. And in the future, if DLL built without `/MT` will be an only option, I can consider your approach used in medical imaging research.