# Build custom Intel MKL DLL which doesn't depend on MSVCR120.DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, intel-mkl

I'm building a [custom Intel MKL DLL (2019 Update 2)](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-windows-developer-guide-using-the-custom-dynamic-link-library-builder-in-the-command-line-mode) using the following command:

```
nmake libintel64 MKLROOT="C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries\windows\mkl" name=win\intel64\custom_mkl interface="lp64"
```

Using `dumpbin` I can see the the `custom_mkl.dll` depends on `MSVCR120.DLL` and `libiomp5md.dll`. The second dll seems to be ok and has to [redistributed as well](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-windows-developer-guide-distributing-your-custom-dynamic-link-library).

Is it possible to build a custom Intel MKL DLL which doesn't depend on `MSVCR120.DLL`?

I saw that there is a `crt = <c run-time library>` parameter but I don't know if this could help.

I cannot directly use the `/MT` option with the above command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get rid of msvcr120.dll/msvcp120.dll dependency in my Release application (VC++ 2013)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27235967/get-rid-of-msvcr120-dll-msvcp120-dll-dependency-in-my-release-application-vc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can build a custom Intel MKL DLL which doesn't depend on `MSVCR120.DLL` using the following command with the addition argument `crt=libcmt.lib`:

```
nmake libintel64 MKLROOT="C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries\windows\mkl" name=win\intel64\custom_mkl interface="lp64" crt=libcmt.lib
```

The following answer helped me:

> There are 4 versions of the CRT link libraries present in vc\lib:
>
> - libcmt.lib: static CRT link library for a release build (/MT)
> - libcmtd.lib: static CRT link library for a debug build (/MTd)
> - msvcrt.lib: import library for the release DLL version of the CRT    (/MD)
> - msvcrtd.lib: import library for the debug DLL version of the    CRT (/MDd)

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3007915/7556646