# Trying to link against INI reader link errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, ini

I'm trying to link to [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12914/INI-Reader-Writer-Class-for-MFC-and-ANSI-C-Windows) INI reader/writer library, but Visual Studio 2012 is giving me a linker error:

`warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'msvrct.lib' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library`

So I try that, and then it gives me four more errors (unresolved external symbols), one of which is `__imp__fprintf`, two of which are a bunch of gibberish and the third of which is `3 unresolved externals`.  I have no idea how to fix this, and would really like to use the library.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resolving LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007312/resolving-lnk4098-defaultlib-msvcrt-conflicts-with)

Comment: I looked there first and tried linking against all four versions of the CRT libraries, that didn't work either, and is exactly why I posted the question.