# Link error 1561 visual studio community 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, sdl

I used the built in NuGet package in visual studio community 2015 in order to download and properly install automatically SDL version 1.2.15.16 for c++.
For some reason, when I try to include the SDL.h file, I get the following error:

"LNK 1561 entry point must be defined .... the packages element is not declared"
Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
#include "SDL.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "HELLOO" << endl;
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What kind of project did you create?

Comment: There isn't a "win32 empty project". Make sure you choose just "empty project" and configure linking and search directories yourself. This issue sounds like a project configuration issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your `main` function should be defined exactly as:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) // note function arguments
```

because SDL library expects it to be in that format.

Comment: even when i changed the main function arguments to match those, it still does not work..I get the same link error

Comment: @Paz_Rosada please be sure that you have selected console win32 application for your project. In project properties, go to `Linker`, then `System` and for `SubSystem` it must be set to `Console`. Or try creating new Win32 console application project.

Comment: Ok, this eliminated the error however, now it is saying "warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'msvcrt.lib' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library"

Comment: Then when I use /NODEFAULTLIB:library I get a ton of other .lib not found errors.

Comment: See this about resolving this warning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007312/resolving-lnk4098-defaultlib-msvcrt-conflicts-with