# LNK2019 when trying to use FreeType 2.10.1?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, lnk2019, freetype

I have been trying to complete the [first tutorial](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/tutorial/step1.html) on the FreeType website. I am using the provided code on the website and I have added the libraries and included the proper include files but I receive 7 LNK2019 errors:

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol FT_Set_Transform referenced in function main \main.obj   1       
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol FT_Set_Char_Size referenced in function main \main.obj   1       
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol FT_New_Face referenced in function main \main.obj    1       
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol FT_Load_Char referenced in function main \main.obj   1       
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol FT_Init_FreeType referenced in function main \main.obj   1       
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol FT_Done_FreeType referenced in function main \main.obj   1       
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol FT_Done_Face referenced in function main \main.obj   1
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230731/unresolved-externals-when-compiling-with-freetype) stack over flow thread and tried what the comments suggested but that made more errors pop up.

I tried [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@jackklpan/using-freetype-in-visual-studio-3ac321ca4cb9) on how to set it up but I still receive the same 7 errors. And the guy in the comments section had the same problem as me but no answers there.

Answer (score 0):

1. Build the `.lib` file on your computer, don't use another one and read `index.html` in the VS project `.sln` directory.
2. Be sure that the configuration when building the `.lib` is similar to the configuration of the project you want to add the file to...
3. Make sure to add it to additional dependencies (Linker -> Input) NOT (Linker->General)
4. Add the full directory (also with the `freetype.lib` name) AFTER `%(AdditionalDependencies)` macro