# "Warning LNK4098 defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library" when setting up vulcan

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, warnings, vulkan

I am trying to set up a Vulcan environment with visual studio. The program runs just fine except for the warning in the title.

I followed a tutorial that shows images for the setting. I have used the exact same settings and have not touched anything else. Here they are:

Includes:

[image]

Linker settings:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It means that your project options for the type of runtime support library you would like to use debug/release, static/dynamic conflict with one or more of the pre-built libraries you are linking with.  Specifically these options [/MD, /MT, /LD (Use Run-Time Library)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/md-mt-ld-use-run-time-library?view=msvc-170) .  Check the description(s) for your pre-built libraries and check they match each other and your project.  When you download pre-built libraries they should tell you this and also the MSVC tool-chain(s) they are compatible with.

Comment: `msvcrt.lib: import library for the release DLL version of the CRT (/MD)`. For your reference: [LNK4098](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007312/resolving-lnk4098-defaultlib-msvcrt-conflicts-with?rq=1)